# don't append "and" clause in where condition when column value is null

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have a query, in which i don't want to append "and" clause in where condition when column value is null e.g

```
select * from x where x.abc = 'ACTIVE' and x.start_date < sysdate and x.end_date > sysdate
```

So in this i want x.end_date will apply only if its value is not null.Not having any stored procedure, just a simple query.

I also want to convert this query into spring-data jpa specifications using criteria builder and predicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `or`:

```
select *
from x
where x.abc = 'ACTIVE' and
      x.start_date < sysdate and
      ( x.end_date > sysdate or x.end_date is null );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the NVL function for this.

```
select * from x
 where x.abc = 'ACTIVE' 
   and x.start_date < sysdate 
   and NVL(x.end_date,sysdate) >= sysdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that the other answers aren't right or good, but I would write this a little differently and I post it here in the hopes that someone has an interesting comment about why one way might be better than another.

Here's what I'd write:

```
select * from x
 where x.abc = 'ACTIVE' 
   and sysdate between x.start_date and nvl(x.end_date,sysdate);
```

To me, that reads: "the current date must fall within the active date range of the record".